# Minecraft Java Edition over VNC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play Java Edition on a Linux PC, and I know how to set up a VNC server. I also have a client (noVNC) for the web and a school chromebook. I managed to configure the VNC to be lag free enough to run games. The application here is obvious.

**START READING HERE**

When I load up Minecraft in the VNC, I'm stuck at either looking at the ground or having almost no mouse control. I have been toggling "Raw Input" and "Touchscreen" options, but nothing is really getting the game playable. Is there a way to fix this, or is there a mod that allows for viewing through the arrow keys? I don't think just moving the mouse through the arrow keys will change anything. I have seen suggestions that recommended this, but in my situation, I don't think it will matter.

Comment: What VNC server?

Comment: @RayWu A display server allowing for remote connection and control of a computer. It doesn't really matter for the question.

Comment: It really does, as that is the thing sending the mouse inputs to Minecraft

Comment: I am using noVNC and I have the same problem

Comment: I am using noVNC and I have the same problem. The reason why it doesn't work is that, while Minecraft locks the X cursor, noVNC doesn't. I think grabbing the cursor and locking it is within the boundaries of HTML5 and Javascript, so I'm going to try some alternatives to noVNC and tell you if they have such capability. 

Comment: @idontknow A PR has actually been opened to allow a extension to the VNC specification to use XWarpPointer. It seems to be going somewhere, and TigerVNC's server supports it too. Hopefully this will allow for Minecraft mouse warping to work, even if everything else is laggy.